# XSD-based autocompletion - can I also have helpful comments appear?

Tags: xml, eclipse, visual-studio, netbeans, autocomplete

I have written a program that parses an .xml file and generates various outputs.    The .xml file is basically a domain-specific language, that succinctly represents the parameters of the generation. I've also created the related .xsd schema - which provides the users of the code generator with auto-completion in most major IDEs: Visual Studio (even in the free express edition) - Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.

For example, when my users type "<Report" and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, they see the available attributes and their types:

```
<Report (Ctrl-space)
   fontHeightInDots:xsd:integer
   isLandscape:xsd:boolean
   ...
```

...etc - that is, the IDEs show the available options at the specific place in the file (elements/attributes). This helps tremendously in creating the aforementioned .xml files, especially given the fact that some of the people doing the editing are analysts, not  developers.

In the two example attributes shown above, it is pretty clear what each attribute is for (I have used lengthy names to that effect). However, in other cases, the name is not enough - and I would love it if I could provide a sort of "help string" in the .xsd, that the editors can show next to the attribute descriptions during auto-completion suggestion showing... For example, for the attribute "height" I would love something like "helpstring" in the .xsd:

```
<xsd:attribute name = "height" helpstring="Height of the associated field macro-flobber in foobared units" use = "optional">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base = "xsd:integer">
            </xsd:restriction>
         </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

... and have the IDEs show the *helpstring* when the autocompletion suggestions come up.

Is there anything like that in modern IDEs's support for .xsd/.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Using `<xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>` for the help string should generally work so that IDEs show it. For your example it would look like

```
<xsd:attribute name = "height" use = "optional">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Height of the associated field macro-flobber in foobared units</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base = "xsd:integer">
        </xsd:restriction>
     </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

At least Visual Studio shows it in the auto-completion popup.

Comment: Indeed, this works for Visual Studio - thanks! I tried it also with Eclipse (Kepler) but saw no improvement there... (my 'hints' didn't show). I will therefore leave this question open for any potential contribution regarding open-source IDEs.